# ? icon after file names in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

In Xcode, sometimes there is a `?`, an `A`, or an `M` in a box to the right of the name of a file. What are the meanings of these icons? Will they have some influence on how the project compiles and runs on the simulator or device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are version control status labels. M means the file is modified, A means it has been added, and ? means your version control system doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: Thank you.i got it.because of the git.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same doubt and after lots of searching I got the answer at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html) under "Keep Track of Your Files’ SCM Status" section:

> M = Locally modified
>
> U = Updated in repository
>
> A = Locally added
>
> D = Locally deleted
>
> I = Ignored
>
> R = Replaced in the repository
>
> – = The contents of the folder have mixed status; display the contents to see individual status
>
> ? = Not under source control

Comment: Links are appreciated, but an answer containing all the relevant information is preferred.